# Choose path in cmake-gui when find_package doesn't find the library

Tags: cmake, cmake-gui

I'm using `find_package` to find the dependencies that I need for my project, as follows:

```
find_package(CURL REQUIRED)
if(CURL_FOUND)
  include_directories(${CURL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
  target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${CURL_LIBRARIES})
endif()
```

But, I would like to know how I can give the option for the user set manually in the cmake-gui when `find_package` fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem by putting `CONFIG` after the `REQUIRED`.

```
find_package(CURL REQUIRED CONFIG)
if(CURL_FOUND)
  include_directories(${CURL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
  target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${CURL_LIBRARIES})
endif()
```